# SQLCMD: WHERE NOT LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

I'm creating a batch file to export data using **SQLCMD**, the command look like this:

```
sqlcmd -S servername -d db1 -o c:\Temp\export.txt -Q "SELECT xColumn, yColumn FROM xTable1 WHERE xColumn NOT LIKE 'AB-C%'" -h-1 -s";" -W
```

The export works fine, but the only issue is `WHERE xColumn NOT LIKE 'AB-C%'`

Even with the **NOT LIKE** command, the data still appear in my export.txt file

**EXPORTED DATA**

[image]

**EXPECTED RESULT**

[image]

I tested my SQL command in SSMS and it works fine. The issue really seems to be when I run `SQLCMD` in Command Prompt

Comment: Could you provide some sample data, especially examples of what should not show up but does?

Comment: Just to clarify -- your command shows 'xxxx%' but your question is about 'U-TC%'.  Want to eliminate the simple thing first and make sure your sqlcmd line actually has 'U-TC%'.

Comment: Double check for weirdness like an accidental invisible character somewhere or a hyphen that is not actually a hyphen but some Unicode version of it -- retype the command (not copy-paste) if you have to. Also, eliminate any chance of looking in the wrong place by varying the export filename.

Comment: @avery_larry the command was edited

Comment: @lurker I added some sample

Comment: Posting text instead of an image is preferred.  Does your sqlcmd line actually hard code 'AB-C%' ??  Or are you using DOS variables?  It seems like your sqlcmd query will not produce the output you show (you're selecting 1 column but the output shows 2).

Comment: If you're calling this from a dos script, you should at least try to use a double percent sign since the percent sign is has special meaning in a batch/cmd file.   _where xColumn NOT LIKE 'AB-C%%'_

Comment: My actual sqlcmd line is 'AB-C%', I tried editing my sqlcmd line so sensitive info wasn't shown. I fixed the command so it reprensent exactly my needs

Comment: @avery_larry Using a double percent sign intead fixed the issue. Thanks